# How to make Fibonacci equation? (Error about uninitialized variable)

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, n;

    printf("What  Fibonacci number would you like?:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return printf("%d", n);
    else
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    printf("%d ", c);

return 0;
```

}

I have made this program for using Fibonacci equation. But I get following errors during compilation:

```
Error   1   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'a' used  d:\computer programming c++\20150923\20150923\20150923-1.c  15  1   20150923
Error   2   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'b' used  d:\computer programming c++\20150923\20150923\20150923-1.c  15  1   20150923
```

How can I fix it??

Comment: It's actually a very simple concept: local variables defined within a function have to be explicitly initialised before use. Global variables, however, if not explicity initialised have `0` value although it's dangerous to rely on that when say, you repeat a loop.

Comment: `int a=0, b=1`...`for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)`

Comment: Besides initializing `a` and `b`, you also need a different variable to use in the `for` loop. Using `c` as the loop variable, and inside the loop, is going to result in bizarre behavior. Finally, if an `int` is 32-bits, you need to limit `n` to less than 45.

Answer (score 6):

Change `int a, b, c, n;` as below in the code.

```
int a = 0, b = 1, c, n; /*Here you initialize the variables a to zero and b to one*/
```

You are trying to access the variables `a` and `b` without initializing it. As they are local variables, they contain garbage values.

When executing this line `c = a + b;`, the value of `a` and `b` are garbage values which may alter the way the code behaves which apparently leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Well the compiler is right, you have to initialize variables before use, e.g.

```
int a = 0, b = 1, c = 0, n = 0; // etc.
```

Otherwise you will trigger [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (which you should try to avoid when using languages such as C or C++) if you read values of uninitialized variables.

And indeed as noted in the comments it doesn't make sense to have `c` as loop index.

Comment: Initializing both `a` and `b` to zero will always print the result as zero.

Comment: @SantoshA: Well, it is up to the OP to assign meaningful values :) I provided example

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the variable declared. Since you didn't declare a and b, compiler is throwing the error.

Also you need to change `c<n` to `c<=n` to get the required fibonacci number

So your final code will look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a=0, b=1, c, n;

    printf("What  Fibonacci number would you like?:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return printf("%d", n);
    else
    for (c = 0; c < =n; c++)
    {
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    printf("%d ", c);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The for loop should use a variable other than c.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to initializing a and b, the code needs to use a separate variable for a loop counter (I used i). By using unsigned int, n can be up to 47, with result = 2971215073. I changed the summation to c = b + a since this corresponds to fib(i) = fib(i-1) + fib(i-2);

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int a=0, b=1, c, i, n;

    printf("What  Fibonacci number would you like?:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n == 0 || n == 1){
        printf("%u\n", n);
        return 0;
    }
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        c = b + a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    printf("%u\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I enter the variable without using get_integer?

Comment: @AbdulazizMukhamedov - I don't see get_integer, perhaps you mean the scanf? You could get rid of that and just set n to a specific value or you could use a double loop, incrementing n in the outer loop.